# customise centova icecast/shoutcst now playing script

Tags: javascript, html, css, icecast

i would like to customize this  script from centavo cast for an ice-cast server  so that i can make it look fit into my website using  css  i have tried a few methods

```css
div.cc_recenttracks_list {
    background-color:gray; 
    border:black;
} 

#cc_recenttracks_tripler105 {
  border: 30px  dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div id="cc_recenttracks_tripler105" class="cc_recenttracks_list">Loading ...</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://albireo.shoutca.st/system/recenttracks.js"  >
```

but i am unable to change the size and the text of the data.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe